# What does 'in the trenches' mean in the context?

Tags: meaning

The following is an excerpt from a TED article, but I am not sure I get it. What does 'in the trenches' that Chris Anderson said mean?

> Chris Anderson: **In the trenches**. Richard Turere, you are something
>   else. We're going to cheer you on every step of the way, my friend.
>   Thank you so much.
>
> > [Richard Turere TED2013 : My invention that made peace with lions](https://www.ted.com/talks/richard_turere_a_peace_treaty_with_the_lions/transcript#t-421257)

Answer (score 1):

"in the trenches"
To have been through a lot together with someone. Specially through hard times.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=in%20the%20trenches

Can be used in the singular.

Richard Turere has been has been working hard on his inventions as well as trying to experiment with his version of an electric fence, therefore Chris Anderson has said, *he has been* "in the trenches".

There is also possibly a reference to the danger of dealing with lions, relating to the dangers of war which relates to the origin of the phrase.

Trench Warfare
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trench_warfare